# How solr handles updated content?

Tags: solr, indexing

I have a content source which contains documents which i want to index using solr. So i installed solr & index source which gives me indexes stored in solr. All is good.

Now my source has document addition say each day its getting 100 more documents i.e. if today is 1000 then tomorrow it would be 1100. Now i want to ensure that solr only indexes those documents which are either added as new or updated say only 100 documents in this case which i also call as delta indexing.

What i observed is that solr goes to indexing by scanning each document & store its index. So in case of delta indexing, how solr would behave?

Will solr index only 100 new documents or solr will scan all 1100 documents but will index only new 100 documents or will solr scan & index all 1100 documents again?

Idea here is to optimize the resource utilization as my source is engaged with heavy traffic from users using it so i am trying to minimize any impact of indexing on it.

Regards.

Comment: Is lucene which is underlying solr, involved in it?

Comment: Could you show your dataConfig? I assume that you have a FileDataSource with an embedded [FileListEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#FileListEntityProcessor)?

Comment: Actually i am not using a filesystem but cms as source.

Comment: Could you post your dataConfig.xml? It is important to know how you import. Only that way we can tell you which import features you may use.

Comment: I am importing indexing using apache manifoldcf crawling which crawls cms & as an output stores index in solr.